# When are threaded frameworks better than event-driven frameworks? (i.e., when is rails better than node.js?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, node.js, frameworks, event-driven

I understand what a threaded framework is (Rails, Django, Symfony2, …). And I understand what an event-driven framework is (Node.js, EventMachine, Twisted, …) and why it's great for live, chat, speed, … In addition they don't seem to cause problems for normal use cases. So:

- What are the drawbacks of event-driven frameworks?
- When should I prefer Rails to Node.js?
- Why aren't all new web servers written with EventMachine, Twisted, or Node.js?
- Will famous frameworks such as Django or Rails become event-driven or die?

Comment: Ahhh, then in that case, we need some moderator cleanup of stale comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> So where are the drawbacks of event-driven frameworks?

1. **Familiarity.** Because event-driven web programming is so different, it will be a while before programmers are comfortable with it. When you are working on a deadline, it’s easier to use what you know, that works.
2. <s>**Library support.** Node has an amazing number of modules, but has a long way to go to catch up with Ruby and Python</s>. *Update: [Node now has more published modules available than Python or Ruby](http://www.modulecounts.com/).*
3. **Deployment.** IT staff are used to threaded frameworks. To take advantage of event-driven frameworks, you’ll want to be asynchronous top-to-bottom. Right now you can develop in Node.js, but will you be able to deploy it effectively, or will you have to administer your own servers?
4. **Unfounded concerns.** Things that seem like problems, but aren’t really:

   - **Event-driven programming is bad for CPU-intensive apps**: The reason being that a CPU-intensive calculation would block the server. This is strictly true, but practically, it is overcome by spawning another process and treating it as I/O, for example, by using Node’s `child_process.exec`.
   - **Event-driven programming is only for apps that need high concurrency**: The reason here is that event-driven programming is “harder” than traditional web app programming, so it’s not worth doing unless you have a good reason to. I personally do not think this is the case—event-driven programming is no more difficult, but it is **very** different. At some point, a critical mass of programmers will be familiar with the event-driven approach and this concern will vanish.
   - **Event-driven programming is a mess of nested callbacks.** This may be true when you first learn it, but eventually you’ll discover how to structure your code in a readable way.
5. **Documentation.** The documentation for Node and its 3rd-party libraries is terrible, usually consisting of nothing more than a `README.md`. Coming from the Python world, where we are used to excellent documentation, this is a big drawback. This is slowly getting better (we need more documentation [like this](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/)).

> When should I prefer Rails to Node.js?

- When you or your team just prefer Ruby over JavaScript.
- When you or your team are not familiar with Node and you need to get the job done.
- When you need to use functionality that’s in Rails that Node doesn’t have yet.
- When you need to deploy to existing Rails-based infrastructure.
- When you have to convince management that you should use Node.js, but you don’t want to be the one to take the fall if the project fails.

> Why all new web server are not written with EventMachine, Twisted, or Node.js?

See above.

> Will famous framework as Django or Rails turn event-driven or die?

Django and Rails will be around a long time. There are lot of apps in those frameworks, and there’s no reason to rewrite them. And there is a large talent pool, which is often a consideration when developing a new web app.

(But see [this Quora answer](http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-developing-in-node-js-versus-Python) from the lead developer of Django, endorsing Node).

Comment: As a rails developer, I'd want to add that in many cases, the npm packages currently are better than ruby gems, with upward tendency.

Comment: One thought to the quora link: there is another key feature of node, which is even an unfair advantage. "One language to rule them all". Once you are familiar with node.js & js itself, you are able to: write frontend-/client-apps, serverside-code, mobile apps (eg. with phonegap), desktop apps (eg. with node-webkit), query your database (mongoDBs query language *is* javascript), and have fun with webservices and JSON, since this is a nearly no-brainer when you use JS from top to bottom.

Comment: This is a very good answer. It should be echoed in all threads :)